# What is the vcgencmd command?

Tags: linux

I know what it *does*, but what does the name *mean*?  Is it a acronym?  In one sentence, how would you explain vcgencmd to someone new to Linux?

Comment: Note that `vcgencmd` isn't a linux artifact.  It is specific to the Pi (and perhaps other devices with Broadcom VideoCore processors).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`vc` stands for VideoCore. `gen` might stand for general. `cmd` for command.

---

As guessed from this comment

```
/* Initialise general command service. Returns it's interface number.     
This initialises the host side of the interface, it does not send 
anything to VideoCore. */
```

found in `vcgencmd.h` as seen [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/vcgencmd.h) and the fact that this tool is used to issue a broad range of *general commands* to the VideoCore.

Answer (score 4):

A more friendly link [vcgencmd](https://elinux.org/RPI_vcgencmd_usage)

The following are commands I find useful

```
vcgencmd get_config int
vcgencmd get_config str

for src in arm core h264 isp v3d uart pwm emmc pixel vec hdmi dpi ; do \
    echo -e "$src:\t$(vcgencmd measure_clock $src)" ; \
done

for id in core sdram_c sdram_i sdram_p ; do \
    echo -e "$id:\t$(vcgencmd measure_volts $id)" ; \
done

vcgencmd get_mem arm && vcgencmd get_mem gpu
```

`vcgencmd display_power`

`vcgencmd get_throttled`

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=147781&start=50#p972790 for interpretation of get_throttled